# How to easily publish written updates on a static website?

Tags: html, css, web

So, I have a website made in HTML and CSS. It's about a game project and I want to be able to publish my own updates in this fashion:

```
etc

11/05/2017
New character added!

10/05/2017
Game version 1.1 released!

09/05/2017     
Game version 1.0 released!

etc
```

Is there a widget or some convenient way to publish updates like that without having to direct edit the html code?

Comment: ... the short answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a static page and all you're going to be doing is adding a few lines every month or two about updates, just edit the HTML when needed.

That being said, there are many ways to do what you are looking to do. However, for such a simple page, my advice would be just to edit the html.